# Why does this trivial function has "Gas requirement high: infinite"?

Tags: remix, gas, warnings

I wrote this trivial contract in Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract HelloWorld {  
    function greet() public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return bytes32('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

I got the warning: "Gas requirement of function HelloWorld.greet() high: infinite".

This is very strange since I do not have any strings or dynamic arrays. How can I get rid of this warning and have clean compilation?

Comment: how you get this warning? Remix is showing 220 (execution cost) as gas estimation for that function

Comment: I just paste the code into Remix and click "start to compile"

Comment: I did the same but I can't reproduce your problem and in the contract details I got a normal gas estimation.

Comment: Same here, it says 220 gas.

Answer (score 1):

Leave default parameters in remix for `Gaslimit` and `wei` - dont touch it. Set it in MetaMask. It`s helped me, since I had same issue.